# how to use gsub to remove a complex pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub, data-cleaning

I am trying to use gsub() to clean my text dataset which is in csv format. Right now a sample row of my data is like :

```
"5.0\t/gp/customer-reviews/R3M62HO4M6LXE6?ASIN=0439023521\tEngaging. Brutal but engaging!\t\"Wow.  I was barely able to put this book down for a second after the first few pages got me completely hooked.
```

I want to remove the beginning string which is providing nothing and remove all \t\ or \t so get the expected result like

```
"Engaging.  Brutal but engaging!"Wow.  I was barely able to put this book down for a second after the first few pages got me completely hooked.
```

I tried to use

```
gsub('\\t\\', "", comment, fix=TRUE)
```

to remove \t\ but it didn't work. 
And the beginning string is too complicated I am having trouble in coding the right pattern expression.

Comment: "providing nothing"? What does that mean?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it means the non-standard English string does have any information I want..

Comment: But `customer-reviews` looks standard to me

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
gsub(".*\\d+\t|\t", "", comment)
```

Comment: Do you think there won't be any "non-nothing" digits in the input string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I am not sure if the OP wants a general pattern to be matched

Comment: @PatrickD: If a "meaningful" non-last column ends with digits (say, with year, or some product, etc. ID), it will remove too much.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use `stringr` library:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(val,".*\\t(?=[:alnum:])","")
```

Using **gsub**:

```
gsub(".*\\t(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])", "", val,perl=T)
```

**or**  `gsub(".*\\t(?=[[:alnum:]])", "", val,perl=T)`

**Output**:

```
 > str_replace(val,".*\\t(?=[:alnum:])","")
[1] "Engaging. Brutal but engaging!\t\"Wow.  I was barely able to put this book down for a second after the first few pages got me completely hooked."
```